# Android spinner drop down with non selected items only

Tags: android

How to show spinner drop down with only the items which is not currently selected like below images

[image: When following is selected]

Drop down list when spinner with FOLLOWING as current item is clicked
[image: Click on drop down when following is selected]

[image: When new is selected]

Drop down list when spinner with NEW as current item is clicked
[image: Click on drop down when new is selected]

Comment: You can keep the active item in a variable and set/get it on selected item change. While setting a new item as active...add the original active item back to the adapter and remove the selected one from the adapter.

Answer (score 0):

There is no default setup for that usecase. You need the change the Data-Set of the [`SpinnerAdapter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SpinnerAdapter.html) (Model) or change the Adapter used by your Spinner in the [`onItemSelected`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener.html) method and save the selected Item in a sparate variable. A Spinner always displays alle Items in from the Spinner Adapter. There is also not the option to add an emty cell.